# How to select a track in popcorn.js using a string and play it?

Tags: javascript, string, sockets, eval, popcornjs

So, here's the skinny:

Running popcorn.js on a youtube video and separate audio loops. Each one is a track like 'video' and 'audio1' etc.

I have user interaction over a sockets that is sending commands to the window as strings like "Play_audio1". This string is then parsed using **split**.

so we get:

```
var messageArray = message.split("_");
```

thus messageArray[0] is my command, and messageArray[1] is what track to do it to.

**THE PROBLEM**

I'm trying to execute the code to select the track using window, and run the popcorn function **play()** on it, but it aint working. Shoots back undefined.

```
case 'Play':
   window[messageArray[1]][play]();
break;
```

Where's my mistake here?

eval() works, but I heard it was the devil.

**EDIT:**

To help add to this, I'll include a popcorn.js track code:

```
var audio1 = Popcorn.smart( "#audio1", "audiofile1.wav",{
        frameAnimation: true
     });
```

and in your html you have

```
<audio id="audio1"></audio>
```

popcorn.js fills it with your selected file, and to play, you normally just use

```
audio1.play();
```

Comment: what is returned by this : window["audio1"]?

Comment: I set a var track = window["audio1"] and tried track.play().
this returned "undefined is not a function"

adding just window["audio1"] did nothing and had no return.

Comment: type it into the console and see what it returns

Comment: Interestingly I get:  <audio id="audio1" class="hide"><video id="popcorn-video-1421939269162" loop="" src="trailer_audio/M_Loop_1_Title.wav"></video></audio>

Comment: I was expecting something else. This might help you, but I don't know how. So, let's explore something else : what was the code that worked with the eval() ?

Comment: I think that document.getElementById("audio1").play(); might work. But I don't think it's good practice

Comment: The code that worked with eval was simply

var playcommand = messageArray[1]+".play()";
eval(playcommand);

Comment: So, it seems the window command is not getting my js var audio1, but instead is getting the html with the ID "audio1".  I tried changing the html ID and now window["audio1"] returns undefined.

Comment: within a switch, case 'audio1' : audio1.play(); break; might be an option?

Comment: This definitely works, but I am looking for an option without switch so I can easily send a play command to any number of tracks because the system is going to be used for numerous purposes with anywhere from 1 to 20 tracks

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you're using messageArray[1] as an index for window. Maybe you should try to create a variable with that value first. Then use it inside window.

`var audioFile = messageArray[1];`

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. Returns "play is not defined"

Comment: Try to do something like this:  `window.track = messageArray[1]; window.command = messageArray[0];`